# Does DC voltage affect the frequency?

Tags: rf, analog, oscillator, radio, oscillation

Does DC voltage supplied to the tank circuit impact its frequency?

[image]

Imagine that varactor is just a normal fixed capacitor, but for some reason there's voltage supplied between the capacitors. Ignore audio input, too. Will this DC voltage impact frequency? I'm thinking that this DC voltage could fasten the charging of capacitors, and thus increase the frequency.

Comment: The main tank component is an inductor and that inductor will ensure than there is minimal DC voltage across it. That's how inductors work.

Comment: Changing a part of the schematic ... can "change" the oscillator frequency ... If DC voltage is changing through P1, (P1 changing value), attenuated by 10nF (should be proved ... by simulation).

Comment: If you don't regulate the voltage supply to tuning pot P1, yes. Also remember there are capacitances in the transistor; the C-B junction is a reverse biased diode, can act as a varicap diode to some extent.

Comment: The extremely simple circuit will also change its RF frequency if something moves towards or away from the antenna. My FM transmitter uses a voltage regulator for the RF oscillator and uses a RF buffer stage to separate the antenna from the oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Especially ceramic capacitor will be affected. Their capacitance can vary greatly over the specified voltage. More information in this Kemet note:
https://www.digikey.com/Site/Global/Layouts/DownloadPdf.ashx

In practice, you can often overcome the problem with polymer film capacitors.

Comment: Specifically this is true of capacitors using high-κ dielectrics. So, X7R, Y5V, and the like. C0G ceramics are essentially constant capacitance regardless of bias voltage. Film capacitors and electrolytics also don't show much in the way of capacitance variation. (though electrolytics aren't really a good choice for a tank circuit)

Answer (score -1):

All semiconductor junctions have capacitance that does change with reverse bias voltage .Varicap diodes do this too but in a more specified manner .Your transistor T1 does this so there will be some frequency variation with DC volts because T1 is connected to the tank .Its parasitic capacitance is a significant % of the effective resonant capacitance.

Comment: The question was that if varicap is swapped to a cap